# How to select fonts more specifically in cairo?

Tags: python, fonts, cairo, pycairo

In `cairo`, fonts can be specified by their family name, e.g. 'HelveticaNeueLTStd'. Then, weights and styles can be defined by `cairo.FONT_WEIGHT_[NORMAL|BOLD]` and `cairo.FONT_SLANT_[NORMAL|OBLIQUE|ITALIC]`, which are constants with integer values. Only these 2 and 3 options are built in. I am wondering, how to select specific weights and styles in case the family have more of them? E.g. Light, Semi-bold, etc.

I am using `pycairo 1.10.0` in `python 2.7`, although these things looks the same in any language.

I could find the solution by guessing, so I will answer my question, but still I am wondering if this is the standard way of doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Font files have various names and other annotations. In FontForge, you can find these listed in menu `Element > Font info`. Here as I found `cairo` is able to identify the font by its `TTF names > Family` or which is the same its `WindowsString`. In case of Adobe's Helvetica Neue light this string has the value `'HelveticaNeueLT Std Lt'`. Then selecting the font by this name, and setting the slant and weight to normal, the light weight will be used:

```
context.select_font_face('HelveticaNeueLT Std Lt', \
    cairo.FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, cairo.FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL)
```

It is possible to find font names by many softwares. On Linux `fontconfig` is able to list fonts, and the name in the second column what cairo recognizes:

```
$ fc-list | grep HelveticaNeue
...
/usr/share/fonts/.../HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf: Helvetica Neue LT Std,HelveticaNeueLT Std Lt:style=45 Light,Regular
...
$ fc-list | sed 's/.*:\(.*,\|\s\)\(.*\):.*/\2/'
...
HelveticaNeueLT Std Lt
...
```